# What's the origin of the name of the Tantive IV?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, a-new-hope, names, rogue-one

[Tantive IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantive_IV) is the ship used by Leia in *Rogue One* and *A New Hope*.

[image]

*Tantive* has the feel of the end of an English adjective. (I think of *substantive*.)   This wouldn't be dissimilar to the names of Darths (in*Vader*, in*Sidious*, *Maul*) which are inspired by evil-sounding English words.

## Do we have any (presumably out-of-universe) explanation for the selection of this name?

Less likely:  Any explanation for the selection of the numeral *IV*?

Comment: Possibly named after the [planet called Tantive IV?](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tantive_IV_(planet)) Just a guess, I don't know enough to make an answer.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Unlikely, since the planet is Legends and was likely invented after the ship was named.

Comment: I've had another look and I can't find anything more to add to my answer. Is there anything more you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: I think that the inspiration for the name of Darth Vader was a take on the German word for *Father*, which is *Vater*, and that the intended "hidden meaning" was a kind of wordplay on "Dark Father"

Comment: @Sekhemty Vader is Dutch, not German.

Comment: @steenbergh Thanks for the clarification, I do not speak Dutch. Anyway, I wrote that the German word is *Vater*, not *Vader*.

Answer (score 12):

### In-Universe

According to the [Star Wars: Blueprints - Rebel Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_Rebel_Edition) factbook, the Tantive IV was *re*named in honour of representatives from the distant Tantive system.

> The Corellian Engineering Corvette CR90 is the starship of choice for
>   everyone from respectable diplomats to notorious pirates. More than a
>   decade before the Clone Wars, Queen Mazicia Organa of the planet
>   Alderaan commissioned the Star of Alderaan to serve as a consular
>   vessel for Senator Agrippa Aldrete. **After the queen's son, Bail
>   Organa, ascended to Viceroy and became a Senatorial representative, he
>   renamed the ship the Tantive IV in tribute to visiting ambassadors
>   from the Tantive system.** It served House Organa for 30 years until its
>   capture by the Empire, after which Darth Vader ordered it be
>   destroyed.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Blueprints - Rebel Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_Rebel_Edition)</sup></sub>

[Star Wars Insider Magazine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_90) identifies the fourth planet of the Tantive System as having engaged in an exchange of arts and artists with Alderaan prior to the renaming of the ship.

> The fourth planet in the Tantive system is home to the Tantive Gallery
>   of Progressive Arts, a sister gallery to Alderaan's own Aldera Museum
>   of Modern Expression. **A cultural exchange program of art and artists
>   preceded the naming of the starship.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Insider #90](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_90)</sup></sub>

---

[image]
<sub><sup>**Image Courtesy of [The Official Star Wars Fact File #11 - "Tantive IV: Blockage Runner"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_11)**</sup></sub>

### Out of Universe

The ship's name wasn't included in the original script or film novelisation.
The ship was merely referred to as a "blockade runner".

> *The awesome yellow planet of Tatooine emerges from a total eclipse,
>   her two moons glowing against the darkness. A tiny silver spacecraft,
>   a Rebel Blockade Runner firing lasers from the back of the ship, races
>   through space.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Final Draft Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html)</sup></sub>

The name 'Tantive IV' was subsequently added by Brian Daley for the (NPR) Star Wars Radio Play. According to Lucasfilm's Pablo Hidalgo (in [Star Wars Insider #90](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_90)), the name was based on the obscure English word "[Tantivy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tantivy)" meaning 'to gallop at full speed'

Comment: So I guess Tantive III from Episode 3 was named after the third planet of that system? I wonder what was on it

Comment: are those resources Disney / official canon? (still gets my vote - just curious)

Comment: @NKCampbell - All of the references above are considered "Legends" canon. The name Tantive IV is fully (Disney) canon, but the explanation of where the name *came from* is not.

Comment: In early works (such as the 1982 Jedi Master's Quiz Book, which was, admittedly, complied by a middle school student), it was often unclear whether "Blockade Runner" was the proper name of the ship, the name of its model/series, or merely a description of its function.

Comment: No explanation of how the word came to be ?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - None, I'm afraid. It appears to be an original creation  of Daley's. There's no specific indication  that he was referring to a planet or simply that it was the fourth Tantive ship.

Answer (score 3):

The word "tantivy" was A.Word.A.Day's 'Word of the Day' a few days ago (https://wordsmith.org/words/tantivy.html). Made me think of this ship. It means:
adverb: At full gallop; at full speed.
noun: A fast gallop; rush.
adjective: Swift.

Good name for a fast ship.

Comment: Is there anything that suggests these two are similar. While certainly likely, canon sources stating the fact would be beneficial to your answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad "Tantive" and "tantivy" look similar, which would possibly be the connection.  As the answer is an out-of-universe explanation, there can be no "canon sources stating the fact". Mind you, Safari's spellcheck doesn't think "tantivy" is a word